# Saving the BLOB data to a file via OLE processes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to export data from SQL Server to a file. The data is a `.jpg`. I found a script that would do so however whenever i run it I get a not any error message. and file not create in folder Please help me

```
DECLARE xArgsEntryImg CURSOR FOR 
                        SELECT TOP 1
                            CONVERT(varbinary(max), E.ENTRY_IMAGE, 1) AS img1,
                            CONVERT(varchar(50), E.TKT_NO) + 'IMG1.jpg' AS img,
                            T.TicketNo
                        FROM
                            ITNLTCS_IMAGE.dbo.ICS_ENTRY_IMAGE E
                        INNER JOIN 
                            fms25.dbo.tblTagTransaction T ON E.TKT_NO = T.TicketNo
                        INNER JOIN 
                            FMS25.dbo.ReqPayViolationMessage m ON (T.TagTransactionPk = m.TagTransactionPk)
                        WHERE
                            NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1  
                                        FROM tblImgUploadLog I 
                                        WHERE ImgType = 1 
                                          AND T.TicketNo = I.TicketNo)
    
DECLARE @PathForEntryImg nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @ImageDataForEntryImg varbinary(max);
DECLARE @FilenameForEntryImg NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @TicketNoForEntryImg bigint;
    
OPEN xArgsEntryImg
        
FETCH xArgsEntryImg INTO @ImageDataForEntryImg, @FilenameForEntryImg, @TicketNoForEntryImg

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @FullPathToOutputFileforEntryImg NVARCHAR(max);
        DECLARE @FileName varchar(4000) = 'D:\FMS\IMAGES\CURRENT\a.jpg'
        DECLARE @ObjectTokenEntryImg INT
    
        EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectTokenEntryImg OUTPUT; -- Create Object
        EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectTokenEntryImg, 'Type', 1;
        EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectTokenEntryImg, 'Open'; 
        EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectTokenEntryImg, 'Write', NULL, @ImageDataForEntryImg; 
        EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectTokenEntryImg, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @FileName, 2; 
        EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectTokenEntryImg, 'Close'; 
        EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectTokenEntryImg; 
    END TRY         
    BEGIN CATCH
    END CATCH

    FETCH NEXT From xArgsEntryImg INTO @ImageDataForEntryImg, @FilenameForEntryImg, @TicketNoForEntryImg
END 

CLOSE xArgsEntryImg
DEALLOCATE xArgsEntryImg
```

Comment: And *what* is that "non-descriptive* error??

Comment: @marc_s not any error but not file create in folder

Comment: @GenishParvadia is the select query returning any records?

Comment: @Coder1991 yes return 1 row with varbinary data

Comment: You don't check the return status on each and every `sp_OA*` method, so of course you don't see error messages. You retrieve error messages via `sp_OAGetErrorInfo` after any `sp_OA*` method that returns a non-zero return status. That said these methods rely on OLE32 so aren't guaranteed to work without quirks on 64-bit systems and are definitely not supported on SQL Server for Linux.

Comment: Also, `ADODB.Stream` doesn't do what you're trying to do. It persists record sets into XML format blobs.